# Laravel - Select box

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following select box which lists the all users. I need list users only which groupID is==3 How can I do that ?

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="form-group  " >
<label for="Staff" class=" control-label col-md-4 text-left"> Staff </label>
<div class="col-md-7">
<select name='Staff' rows='5' id='Staff' class='select2 '   ></select> 
</div> 
<div class="col-md-1">
</div>
</div>
```

Controller

use App\Http\Controllers\controller; use App\Models\Adminorders; use Illuminate\Http\Request; use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator as Paginator; use Validator, Input, Redirect ;

```
class AdminordersController extends Controller {

    protected $layout = "layouts.main";
    protected $data = array();  
    public $module = 'adminorders';
    static $per_page    = '10';

    public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf', array('on'=>'post'));
        $this->model = new Adminorders();
        $this->modelview = new  \App\Models\Orderdetail();
        $this->info = $this->model->makeInfo( $this->module);
        $this->access = $this->model->validAccess($this->info['id']);

        $this->data = array(
            'pageTitle' =>  $this->info['title'],
            'pageNote'  =>  $this->info['note'],
            'pageModule'=> 'adminorders',
            'return'    => self::returnUrl()

        );

        $this->data['subgrid']  = (isset($this->info['config']['subgrid']) ? $this->info['config']['subgrid'][0] : array()); 
    }

    public function getIndex( Request $request )
    {

        if($this->access['is_view'] ==0) 
            return Redirect::to('dashboard')
                ->with('messagetext', \Lang::get('core.note_restric'))->with('msgstatus','error');

        $sort = (!is_null($request->input('sort')) ? $request->input('sort') : 'SiparisID'); 
        $order = (!is_null($request->input('order')) ? $request->input('order') : 'asc');
        // End Filter sort and order for query 
        // Filter Search for query      
        $filter = '';   
        if(!is_null($request->input('search')))
        {
            $search =   $this->buildSearch('maps');
            $filter = $search['param'];
            $this->data['search_map'] = $search['maps'];
        } 


        $page = $request->input('page', 1);
        $params = array(
            'page'      => $page ,
            'limit'     => (!is_null($request->input('rows')) ? filter_var($request->input('rows'),FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : static::$per_page ) ,
            'sort'      => $sort ,
            'order'     => $order,
            'params'    => $filter,
            'global'    => (isset($this->access['is_global']) ? $this->access['is_global'] : 0 )
        );
        // Get Query 
        $results = $this->model->getRows( $params );        

        // Build pagination setting
        $page = $page >= 1 && filter_var($page, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false ? $page : 1; 
        $pagination = new Paginator($results['rows'], $results['total'], $params['limit']); 
        $pagination->setPath('adminorders');

        $this->data['rowData']      = $results['rows'];
        // Build Pagination 
        $this->data['pagination']   = $pagination;
        // Build pager number and append current param GET
        $this->data['pager']        = $this->injectPaginate();  
        // Row grid Number 
        $this->data['i']            = ($page * $params['limit'])- $params['limit']; 
        // Grid Configuration 
        $this->data['tableGrid']    = $this->info['config']['grid'];
        $this->data['tableForm']    = $this->info['config']['forms'];   
        // Group users permission
        $this->data['access']       = $this->access;
        // Detail from master if any

        // Master detail link if any 
        $this->data['subgrid']  = (isset($this->info['config']['subgrid']) ? $this->info['config']['subgrid'] : array()); 
        // Render into template
        return view('adminorders.index',$this->data);
    }   



    function getUpdate(Request $request, $id = null)
    {

        if($id =='')
        {
            if($this->access['is_add'] ==0 )
            return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('messagetext',\Lang::get('core.note_restric'))->with('msgstatus','error');
        }   

        if($id !='')
        {
            if($this->access['is_edit'] ==0 )
            return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('messagetext',\Lang::get('core.note_restric'))->with('msgstatus','error');
        }               

        $row = $this->model->find($id);
        if($row)
        {
            $this->data['row'] =  $row;
        } else {
            $this->data['row'] = $this->model->getColumnTable('tb_orders'); 
        }
        $this->data['fields']       =  \SiteHelpers::fieldLang($this->info['config']['forms']);

        $relation_key = $this->modelview->makeInfo($this->info['config']['subform']['module']);
        $this->data['accesschild'] = $this->modelview->validAccess($relation_key['id']);    
        $this->data['relation_key'] = $relation_key['key'];
        $this->data['subform'] = $this->detailview($this->modelview ,  $this->info['config']['subform'] ,$id );
        $this->data['id'] = $id;
        return view('adminorders.form',$this->data);
    }   

    public function getShow( Request $request, $id = null)
    {

        if($this->access['is_detail'] ==0) 
        return Redirect::to('dashboard')
            ->with('messagetext', \Lang::get('core.note_restric'))->with('msgstatus','error');

        $row = $this->model->getRow($id);
        if($row)
        {
            $this->data['row'] =  $row;
            $this->data['fields']       =  \SiteHelpers::fieldLang($this->info['config']['grid']);
            $this->data['id'] = $id;
            $this->data['access']       = $this->access;
            $this->data['subgrid']  = (isset($this->info['config']['subgrid']) ? $this->info['config']['subgrid'] : array()); 
            $this->data['prevnext'] = $this->model->prevNext($id);
            return view('adminorders.view',$this->data);
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('adminorders')->with('messagetext','Record Not Found !')->with('msgstatus','error');                    
        }
    }   

    function postSave( Request $request)
    {

        $rules = $this->validateForm();
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);  
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $data = $this->validatePost('tb_adminorders');

            $id = $this->model->insertRow($data , $request->input('SiparisID'));
            $this->detailviewsave( $this->modelview , $request->all() ,$this->info['config']['subform'] , $id) ;
            if(!is_null($request->input('apply')))
            {
                $return = 'adminorders/update/'.$id.'?return='.self::returnUrl();
            } else {
                $return = 'adminorders?return='.self::returnUrl();
            }

            // Insert logs into database
            if($request->input('SiparisID') =='')
            {
                \SiteHelpers::auditTrail( $request , 'New Data with ID '.$id.' Has been Inserted !');
            } else {
                \SiteHelpers::auditTrail($request ,'Data with ID '.$id.' Has been Updated !');
            }

            return Redirect::to($return)->with('messagetext',\Lang::get('core.note_success'))->with('msgstatus','success');

        } else {

            return Redirect::to('adminorders/update/'.$request->input('SiparisID'))->with('messagetext',\Lang::get('core.note_error'))->with('msgstatus','error')
            ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        }   

    }   

    public function postDelete( Request $request)
    {

        if($this->access['is_remove'] ==0) 
            return Redirect::to('dashboard')
                ->with('messagetext', \Lang::get('core.note_restric'))->with('msgstatus','error');
        // delete multipe rows 
        if(count($request->input('ids')) >=1)
        {
            $this->model->destroy($request->input('ids'));
            \DB::table('tb_orderdetail')->whereIn('SiparisID',$request->input('ids'))->delete();
            \SiteHelpers::auditTrail( $request , "ID : ".implode(",",$request->input('ids'))."  , Has Been Removed Successfull");
            // redirect
            return Redirect::to('adminorders?return='.self::returnUrl())
                ->with('messagetext', \Lang::get('core.note_success_delete'))->with('msgstatus','success'); 

        } else {
            return Redirect::to('adminorders?return='.self::returnUrl())
                ->with('messagetext','No Item Deleted')->with('msgstatus','error');             
        }

    }   

    public static function display( )
    {
        $mode  = isset($_GET['view']) ? 'view' : 'default' ;
        $model  = new Adminorders();
        $info = $model::makeInfo('adminorders');

        $data = array(
            'pageTitle' =>  $info['title'],
            'pageNote'  =>  $info['note']

        );

        if($mode == 'view')
        {
            $id = $_GET['view'];
            $row = $model::getRow($id);
            if($row)
            {
                $data['row'] =  $row;
                $data['fields']         =  \SiteHelpers::fieldLang($info['config']['grid']);
                $data['id'] = $id;
                return view('adminorders.public.view',$data);
            } 

        } else {

            $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
            $params = array(
                'page'      => $page ,
                'limit'     =>  (isset($_GET['rows']) ? filter_var($_GET['rows'],FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) : 10 ) ,
                'sort'      => 'SiparisID' ,
                'order'     => 'asc',
                'params'    => '',
                'global'    => 1 
            );

            $result = $model::getRows( $params );
            $data['tableGrid']  = $info['config']['grid'];
            $data['rowData']    = $result['rows'];  

            $page = $page >= 1 && filter_var($page, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false ? $page : 1; 
            $pagination = new Paginator($result['rows'], $result['total'], $params['limit']);   
            $pagination->setPath('');
            $data['i']          = ($page * $params['limit'])- $params['limit']; 
            $data['pagination'] = $pagination;
            return view('adminorders.public.index',$data);          
        }


    }

    function postSavepublic( Request $request)
    {

        $rules = $this->validateForm();
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);  
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $data = $this->validatePost('tb_orders');       
             $this->model->insertRow($data , $request->input('SiparisID'));
            return  Redirect::back()->with('messagetext','<p class="alert alert-success">'.\Lang::get('core.note_success').'</p>')->with('msgstatus','success');
        } else {

            return  Redirect::back()->with('messagetext','<p class="alert alert-danger">'.\Lang::get('core.note_error').'</p>')->with('msgstatus','error')
            ->withErrors($validator)->withInput();

        }   

    }   




}
```

Comment: Its just html, pass the data source accordingly.

Comment: You will need to show a lot more code if you are looking for an answer. Try adding the users table structure, controller method that uses this view and the name of the view and someone should be able to help.

Comment: @Mayank Pandeyz Which file do you need to see ? Controller.php ?

Comment: @Rob Fonseca /  id, group_id, username, password, email, first_name, last_name, avatar, active, login_attempt, last_login, created_at, updated_at, reminder, activation, remember_token, last_activity

Comment: That is just your model. You need to post the controller method that renders the view. You should edit your question and ad this info there so everyone who view it can see it without digging through the comments.

Comment: @Rob Fonseca I added controller file also. Thank you.

Comment: Is your form inside adminorders.public.index.blade.php ?

Comment: @Sreejith Hi. The form is inside the form.blade.php. index.blade.php is a table view.